# Use a list of dictionaries to create a new variable in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'One': ['number 1', 'number 1'],'Two': ['number 2', 'number 2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['One', 'Two'])
print(df)
```

I also have this list of dictionaries:

```py
[{'year': '1997', 'name': 'John'}]
```

I would like to be able to take 'year' from the list to create a new variable in `df` titled 'the_year' which has the value set as '1997'. So `new_df` would look like this:

```py
data = {'One': ['number 1', 'number 1'],'Two': ['number 2', 'number 2'],'the_year': ['1997', '1997']}
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['One', 'Two', 'the_year'])
print(new_df)
```

Does anyone know how I would achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What you wrote is very confusing, in this case we ignore everything apart from year in your second list of dictionaries? Why is 1997 assiged twice?

Comment: Do you mean to extract the year and replicate it `n` times? If so you can try this `data = {'One': ['number 1', 'number 1'],'Two': ['number 2', 'number 2'],'the_year': [d[0]['year']]*2}`. Where `d` is the `list` of a `dict`.

Comment: @AlexisDrakopoulos yes ignore everything in the list of dictionaries apart from 'year'. The list could have two dictionaries in it or 100, it doesn't matter. On your second point '1997' is assigned twice because there are two rows in the df. If there were 50 rows, then '1997' would be assigned 50 times

Comment: But does that mean that your second list only has 1 value? What happens if your second list is [{'year': '1997', 'name': 'John'}, {'year': '1999', 'name': 'Dave'}]

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the `year` column from a `DataFrame` constructed from the dicts as records.

```py
data = {'One': ['number 1', 'number 1'],'Two': ['number 2', 'number 2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['One', 'Two'])

data_with_year = pd.DataFrame([{'year': '1997', 'name': 'John'}, {'year': '1998', 'name': 'Florence'}])

new_data = df.copy()
new_data['the_year'] = data_with_year['year']
print(new_data)
```

Gives

```py
        One       Two the_year
0  number 1  number 2     1997
1  number 1  number 2     1998
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'One': ['number 1', 'number 1'],'Two': ['number 2', 'number 2']}
```

You could just create another key `the_year` for `data` before converting the dictionary into a dataframe.

```py
data_with_year = [{'year': '1997', 'name': 'John'}, {'year': '1998', 'name': 'Tony'}]
years = [d['year'] for d in data_with_year]
data['the_year'] = years

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

**Output :**

```
        One       Two the_year
0  number 1  number 2     1997
1  number 1  number 2     1998
```